# New rails project running system tests gives loaderror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Rails new project (6.1) created without tests

```
rails new [project name] -T
```

I then installed rspec 5 and generated a system test that outputted the following error.

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 
capybara System test integration requires Rails >= 5.1
and has a hard dependency on a webserver and `capybara`,
please add capybara to your Gemfile and configure a webserver
(e.g. `Capybara.server = :webrick`) before attempting to use system specs.
No examples found.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing Capybara gem in the Gemfile, as the error suggests, you get this LoadError.

This can happen if you generate rails without tests `rails new [project] -T` and then install RSpec as it does not add Capybara in the Gemfile.

#### Solution

Adding a test group and putting capybara within gets you past this error like so.

```
# Gemfile
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
end
```

Comment: Not sure why this was needed as an answer? The error description is very clear "...please add capybara to your Gemfile". Nothing suggests that `rspec` would install capybara and generating a rails project without a test directory has no impact on this setup either.

Comment: As much as I can remember, I spent time reading about the `Capybara.server` setting and wondering 'does that mean I should be setting puma and in what block?' Before settling on just adding capybara. This was the second time it caught me out, so I wrote a Q/A to make sure there is no third - I assume that eventually the only people visiting this will be confused Gogglers and this will save time for us.  I'm not sure what the point you're making about RSpec?

Comment: You stated *"...then install RSpec as it does not add Capybara in the Gemfile"* but `rspec` has nothing to do with `capybara` just as `capybara` has nothing to do with `rspec` so I am not sure why this is important

Comment: Fair enough. I think of `RSpec` as "batteries included" testing - I expected everything to work once I had installed it, but the feature tests, a core feature, didn't.